# Show Title/Text of ActionBar when landscape

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an action bar where I have to show three icons when portrait. What I want is I want to show icons together with text when displaying landscape.

I've tried the following but no luck:

```
<item 
        android:id="@+id/likes"
        android:showAsAction="withText|always"
        android:icon="@drawable/likes"
        android:title="@string/action_favorites" />
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/recent" 
        android:showAsAction="withText|always" 
        android:icon="@drawable/history"
        android:title="@string/action_recent" />
     <item 
        android:id="@+id/exchange" 
        android:showAsAction="withText|always" 
        android:icon="@drawable/change"
        android:title="@string/action_exchange" />
```

Comment: You can design two layout one for portrait and one for landscape.

Comment: ah creating another folder like "layout-land" thne putting there the menu xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have these values as xml in res/menu directory then you can create similar file with smaller amount of elements in res/menu-land

Comment: I did. I created `menu-land` folder then duplicated the `menu.xml` file from `menu` folder and pasted it there. I put `withText` as value of `showAsAction` attribute but still not displaying the text with icon when landscape

Comment: activity is recreated on orientation change?

Comment: should i put any tracker to trace the restart event? just like overriding the onRestart() event?

Comment: read some book about Android. In Manifets.xml you should not have android:configChanges="orientation" and if you use Fragment then onRetainInstance should be false. In such conditions screen rotion causes the activity to get recreated and new xml files to be loaded.